# Possible to Run Normal Java File Via Browser?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've coded a game in Eclipse (still working on it), is it possible to run it's jar file in browser so that anyone can play right from their browsers instead of downloading jar file?
I.e I upload it on my website so that anyone can play right from the link I provide them.

Comment: Yes and no.  You can [use an Applet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/) to run Java code in a browser.  However, applets have had security issues and Oracle has been slow to fix those issues, so most modern browsers will throw up road blocks telling the user what they are about to do is unsafe.  You can also use a launcher, browsers think downloading an .EXE is perfectly fine.

Comment: Possible, yes.  But the world of Java Applets is [coming to end](https://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation).  Best to use HTML5 or similar for browser game development.

Comment: Is it a desktop swing/awt application?

Comment: One more option for running Java from a browser is [Java Web Start](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml).

Comment: Aren't nowadays both jawas and applets deprecated and removed by most browsers? So what is a solution to this question in 2020?

Answer (score 4):

Consider using Java Web Start with [JNLP](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jnlp-136707.html). You can host a JNLP file on a web server somewhere, along with your jar, and users can use a desktop shortcut pointing to the link, or a browser to open your app. (Using a browser will require having a web page with an applet tag: the article mentions how to do this but doesn't separate the two.)